# Can't Get Selenium WebDriver to Work on Mac

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I downloaded the chrome webdriver and got the chromedriver executable in the /usr/local/bin. Still, the error shows up that "driver is not found" There might be something else wrong with the code too.

```
pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Answer (score 1):

The line of code:

```
pip install selenium
```

is the part of installing [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) i.e. *Configuration*. So it shouln't be part of your script. So you need to remove this line.

Finally, if your usecase is to use [selenium-chromedriver](/questions/tagged/selenium-chromedriver) and [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) you need to initialize the session in the following way:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# or
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver') # presuming chromedriver binary stored at /usr/local/bin
```